# converting a dictionary of dictionaries into strings instead of tuples and then outputting to a file python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have pulled data from a test router providing information about each interface. the data provided is outputted into a dictionary of dictionaries. my wish is to output these to a file.

first problem is that some of the entries are tuples and error messages indicate these need to be strings before they can be output to file. can someone help me iterate through all the dictionaries to first convert the tuples into strings.

I have tried methods such as follows:

```
for t in test2:
    line = ' '.join(str(x) for x in t)
```

but this just gets rid of the data and leaves me the keys.

my code is as follows:

```
from librouteros import connect
api = connect(username='admin', password='', host='192.168.254.1'

test = api(cmd='/interface/print', stats=True)
({'.id': '*1',
'bytes': '418152/157562',
'comment': '',
'disabled': False,
'drops': '0/0',
'dynamic': False,
'errors': '0/0',
'mtu': 1500,
'name': 'ether1',
'packets': '3081/1479',
'running': True,
'type': 'ether'},)
```

the output from this will then be a dictionary of dictionaries with each dictionary being the data collected for a single interface in the format of the code above.

pretty sure I have the outputting to a file thing figured out so right now its more to do with the tuple conversion.

any help is much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: You'd have to iterate over `t.items()` to handle both keys and values, yes. Iterating over `t` gives you only the keys.

Comment: What were you planning to use the file data for, later on? That's important, there are probably better ways to serialise your data to a file.

Comment: right now im just doing a test to put it into a html document to go on a website but how would i use t.items please?

Comment: You can use `t.items()` like this: `for key, value in t.items():` see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: still getting this tuple object has no attribute 'items

Comment: Could you add an example of the dictionary of dictionaries?